Double integral over region between 2 circles
I am trying to evaluate the following double integral over region between $x^2+y^2=a^2$ and $x^2+y^2=b^2$ where (a>b>0);
$\iint_R (x^2y/x^2+y^2) \, dx \, dy$
I had used polar form to solve the double integral but confused about the limit.
$x=r\cos \theta , y=r\sin \theta$
$dxdy=rdrd\theta$
First, I thought limits of $r\rightarrow$ b to a and $\theta \rightarrow$ 0 to 2$\pi$.
However, this result in double integral value to 0 which I wrong.
My teacher told me limit of $\theta$ should be from 0 to $\pi$/2.
Could someone guide me through the correct steps to evaluate this limit?

As written, the integrand is an odd function of $y$, so I would say the double integral over the whole annulus really is zero. Perhaps the region is intended to be restricted to the first quadrant?

Are you able to upload a picture of this?

Yes I had uploaded the picture John

MPW can limit of $\theta$ can range from 0 to 2$pi$ in polar form of any other double integral?

@YogeshTilara Is the integrand $\frac{x^{2}\cdot y}{x^{2}}+y^{2}$ or do you mean $\frac{x^{2}\cdot y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$?

It is second one @ gpmath kindly give what conclusion can be drawn for this problem.

With $f(x,y):=\frac{x^2\cdot y}{x^2+y^2}=r\cdot \cos^2(\theta)\cdot\sin(\theta)$
$$I(\varphi)=\int_0^{\varphi}\int_b^a f(r\cos(\theta),r\sin(\theta))\; r dr d\theta=\int_0^{\varphi}\int_b^a r^2 \cos^2(\theta)\sin(\theta)\; dr d\theta=\frac{1}{9}(a^3-b^3)\cdot(1-\cos^3(\varphi))$$
because $$\int_b^a r^2 dr=\left.\frac{1}{3}r^3\right\rvert_b^a=\frac{1}{3}(a^3-b^3)$$
and
$$\int_0^{\varphi} \cos^2(\theta)\sin(\theta)\, d\theta=\left.-\frac{1}{3}\cos^3(\theta)\right\rvert_0^{\varphi}=\frac{1}{3}(1-\cos^3(\varphi))$$
First quadrant: $I\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=\frac{1}{9}(a^3-b^3)$
Region $R$: $I(2\pi)=0$

Is this limits for $\theta$ also traces over region other than first quadrant or it is for first quadrant only?

@YogeshTilara First quadrant only. Integral over all 4 quadrants evaluates to 0.

Thanks @gpmath for explaining.
